# How to use GDB debug OpenCV programmes?

Tags: debugging, opencv

I wrote an OpenCV program, compiled by gcc -g *.o -o *, run successfully. However, when i try to use gdb debug this program, like gdb cvmat, it doesn't work. How can i use gdb debug an opencv program?

Comment: Paste the error you are getting from gdb.

Comment: Reading symbols from /home/uranus/project/cvmat/cvmat...(no debugging symbols found)...done. while i compile source files with gcc -g option, how that happens?

Answer (score 1):

While your program is compiled with debugging symbols (using the `-g` flag), it sounds like OpenCV was not. Try rebuilding your OpenCV installation with debugging symbols by setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `Debug` or `RelWithDebInfo` when configuring your build with `ccmake`.

Answer (score 1):

I had no luck with `-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.  I could use the resulting library, but I wasn't able to debug inside OpenCV functions.  Using `cmake-gui` didn't fix things for me either.

I was able to debug inside OpenCV by manually compiling the library components that I was interested in...

```
g++ -g -I ../../include/opencv/ -I ../../3rdparty/include/ cxlapack.cpp cxmatrix.cpp ../../lib/libcxcore.so my_source_file.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Combination cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG successfully appends debug information.